# Nginx Reverse Proxy very slow on image upload

Tags: django, nginx

I use Nginx as a Reverse Proxy for a Django Project with Gunicorn.
It is used for https. Everything on the site is loaded fast, except when I send a POST request with multipart form data.

Then it takes 26 seconds for a 2 Megabyte image to process the request. For a 60 Kilobyte image it takes several seconds but still way too long.

I measured the processing time of the Django view with the python time module and got around 80 milliseconds.

During testing on a local development server it took around a second to process the request. And on the deployment server all media files are served quickly. So I guess the cause is an unsuitable configuration of Nginx with the multipart form request.

My conf file is mostly untouched. I tried all StackOverflow solutions with modified cache settings and once with denabled cache but without success. Is there an information and configuration that I missed?

My form header:

```
<form id="configsForm" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
```

Entry in Gunicorn journalctl after execution:

```
- "POST /settings/profileconfigs/ HTTP/1.0" 200
```

Comment: Nginx works fast for me. Can you share the method of the post request to check?

Comment: Thats nice to hear! I am not quite sure what you mean by 'method of the post request'. So I added the form header and the log entry of gunicorn after the execution to the question. I hope that was what you needed. If not let me know.

Comment: I am referring to the code that possibly resides in your views.py. Maybe the problem is not the upload but another possible function or method is causing the delay.

Comment: Ahh thanks. The view is quite long. I checked again and the time needed from the beginning of the function to before return is 75 ms. So I suspect that nginx is causing the time consumption. But if you really need the function I would add it to the question. Did you have to make any settings so that nginx is working fine with multipart requests or did it worked directly? And may I ask with which file types nginx works fast for you?

Comment: I have this config with nginx: https://pastebin.com/TyfsmQja . It works fine with uploads to the media folder and fine when I migrate to minio

Comment: Thank you for sharing your settings! I had them very similar and tried yours out. Sadly it changed nothing on the loading time for the images.

Answer (score 0):

I still found no solution on the nginx level.

But I knew that images with around 100 kB are loaded quite fast. So I compressed the image in the file input with JavaScript before sending it to the server. This works fine with .jpeg images.

Comment: could you please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408894/nginx-removes-contents-from-multipart-formdata